# Is it possible to use Cassandra NoSQL database from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cassandra

I have tried to use a Ruby bindings for Cassandra database by installing binding:

```
sudo gem install cassandra
```

and attempting to load it:

```
require 'cassandra'
```

Unfortunately, this fails with error:

```
Gem::LoadError: RubyGem version error: thrift_client(0.8.1 not ~> 0.7.0)
```

I have fixed it by installing outdated dependency:

```
sudo gem install thrift_client -v "~> 0.7.0"
```

But after that another error is raised that i don't know how to fix:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- thrift_client/connection
```

Tested on Ubuntu 11.10 and OSX 10.7, with both Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3-p0. Is i something i'm doing wrong or Cassandra and Ruby are not intended to work together?

Comment: Does the second error ("no such file to load") happen immediately when you `require 'cassandra'`, or somewhere else?

Comment: @Dylan Immediately, it's Cassandra internal error. You can test it yourself.

Comment: Well when I follow your exact steps, I can reproduce the first error, but after installing the 0.7.0 version, `require 'cassandra'` works just fine. Have you tried removing *all* thrift_client versions to make sure 0.8.0 isn't interfering?

Comment: @Dylan sure thing i have tried removing 0.8.0 version. What operating system and Ruby version are you using?

Comment: i think that the cassandra-gem is not maintained anymore. at least the github repo is missing. did you try using cassandr-ruby? http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-ruby/

Comment: @phoet Is it installable as a gem, do i need to compile it or what? Wiki on the project page doesn't look like typical Ruby code.

Comment: i have no idea. i just tried installing the cassandra gem myself and ran into the same issues. i assume that it's out of date and that nobody is maintaining it at the moment. despite the fact that the repo on github is just gone...

Comment: @phoet The repository mentioned on official Cassandra website, https://github.com/twitter/cassandra seems to be active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the latest commits on github indicate that they are going to push a new version soon. this one might not have the dependency problems mentioned.

i created a gist that should help you setup your project correctly: https://gist.github.com/1878226

Answer (score 2):

Me and my team had plenty of problems with using the original cassandra gem.
The gem seems to have been abandoned by the developers (last, 0.12.1, release happened on August 22, 2011) and is not compatible with thrift v0.8. Using thrift v0.7 was not an option for us as you can't compile it on Ubuntu without hacking some .c files, so we've decided to use mcmire-cassandra gem instead - http://rubygems.org/gems/mcmire-cassandra .

Even though mcmire did an excellent job with fixing the original gem, ruby client for cassandra is still behind the competition in terms of functionality provided. If you expect high load and need features like connection pooling for example you might consider using either Python or Java clients, which support it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if using JRuby is an option for you? In that case you'd be able to use the Java client for Cassandra and I expect to have both better support and better results with it.